# How can we generate email failure notice?

Tags: java

How can we generate email failure notice in java if the email is not delivered due to issues like email address does not exists or delivery failure etc.... something like yahoomail  notifications

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

how to generate email failure notices like Yahoo mail etc C# .NET

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10140544/how-to-generate-email-fai.aspx

Comment: I think he copy-pasted the question from exactly that thread, only changing C# to Java :)